# Way to change reference variable for jsondata

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to reference the elements inside a 'parsed' JSON data object `jsonData`.]. I can reference the element by putting the actual name, same as in the example below. If I don't know which element to reference, how can I use a variable to refer to multiple elements?

This is my code:

```
var received = {};
received = search_options();
var test = received['data']; //variable prepared for replacing actual element name

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'timeline');
data.addColumn('number', 'solid_t2');
var dataArray = [];
var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data1);
for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
    dataArray.push([jsonData[i].timeline.substring(0, 5), parseInt(jsonData[i].solid_t2)]); 
    // How can I replace 'solid_t2'(above line) with a variable?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jsonData[i][test]
```

I personally prefer to save references before accessing a multidimensional array for better readability.

```
var firstLevelElementOfJson = jsonData[i];
requiredSecondLevelElement = firstLevelElementOfJson[ test ];
```

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it solves your issue.